# Need to modify matrix rain in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've tried to modify this script so that instead of having the rain composed of  random chars it display a name, let's say, just for the pourpose of this exercise, "John Smith". What I want is that on every column the name 'John Smith' is falling down from top to bottom with the same ghost effect of the original script.
Just for info I found this script on "https://github.com/javascriptacademy-stash/digital-rain".
On every column I should see the name written like this:

[image]

So from the top border I can see John coming out first followed by Smith. That's what I want to change but it seems so difficult to just change the string.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width/fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for( let x = 0; x < columns; x++ ) {
    rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
    context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

    for(let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++)
    {
        const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
        context.fillText(text, i*fontSize, rainDrops[i]*fontSize);
        
        if(rainDrops[i]*fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975){
            rainDrops[i] = 0;
        }
        rainDrops[i]++;
    }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="Matrix"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version where each column starts at a random position in "John Smith".

The chars cycle through "John Smith " and wrap around.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const name = 'John Smith ';

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width / fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  rainDrops[x] = {
    position: 1,
    nameIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length) // Start at a random position in the name
  };
}

const draw = () => {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
  context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

  for (let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
    const text = name.charAt(rainDrops[i].nameIndex);
    context.fillText(text, i * fontSize, rainDrops[i].position * fontSize);

    rainDrops[i].nameIndex = (rainDrops[i].nameIndex + 1) % name.length;

    if (rainDrops[i].position * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
      rainDrops[i].position = 0;
      rainDrops[i].nameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length);
    }
    rainDrops[i].position++;
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Matrix"></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh it works!! Thank you so much you've been so kind.